# How do I use pgfkeys .try handler for selecting a choice that could not exist?

Tags: pgfkeys, tikzset

The problem is the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\cmd{0}
\tikzset{/test/.is choice,
    /test/one/.code={\def\cmd{A}},
    /test/two/.code={\def\cmd{B}},
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{/test=one} \cmd
\tikzset{/test/two} \cmd
\tikzset{/noexist/.try=a} % works
\tikzset{/test/.try=three} \cmd % does not work
\end{document}
```

I expected that the `.try` handler would work by ignoring the key set (because `three` option is not there); instead I got an error

```bash
Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'three' unknown in choice key '/test'.
I am going to ignore this key.
```

So --- how can I *try to set* a value of an `is choice` key?

Comment: By checking [how handler `/.is choice` is implemented](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/d835e0312028e7e398626bdd77e5effeaab280f0/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex#L870-L879), especially the part `.code=\def\pgfkeys@was@choice{##1}\expandafter\pgfkeysalso\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/##1},`,  it seems `\pgfkeys{/test=three/.try}` works.

Answer (score 2):

An [implementation](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/d835e0312028e7e398626bdd77e5effeaab280f0/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex#L870-L879) dependent trick is to use `/.try` on the choice value, not on the key: `/test=three/.try`. This will lead to `/test/three/.try` hence works.

Redefining handler `/.unknown` is a more general solution.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\def\cmd{0}
\pgfkeys{/test/.is choice,
    /test/one/.code={\def\cmd{A}},
    /test/two/.code={\def\cmd{B}},
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/test=one} \cmd
\pgfkeys{/test/two} \cmd
\pgfkeys{/noexist/.try=a} % works

\pgfkeys{/test=three/.try} \cmd % works

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/test/.unknown/.code=%
  \PackageWarning{pkg}
    {Unknown choice `\pgfkeys@was@choice' for key `\the\pgfkeys@pathtoks'}}
\makeatother
\pgfkeys{/test=three} \cmd % works too
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is ok if planned in advance :-). I use the `/test/three/.try` workaround to make the "style file" of `circuitikz` compatible with older versions of the package, that have no `three` option... and given that they are old version, I cannot change the `.unknow` handler! Thanks anyway, nice to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a self-answer to a. help others b. see if there are some more elegant solutions!

The problem is that the key `/test` **does** exist, so the `.try` is basically ignored. The solution is to use the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\cmd{0}
\tikzset{/test/.is choice,
    /test/one/.code={\def\cmd{A}},
    /test/two/.code={\def\cmd{B}},
    % /test/three/.code={\def\cmd{C}},
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{/test=one} \cmd
\tikzset{/test/two} \cmd
\tikzset{/noexist/.try=a} % works
\tikzset{/test/three/.try} \cmd %works
\end{document}
```